# Marketo, Velocity Scripting for Emails and templates

Tags: velocity, marketo

I'm new to scripting in Marketo, and I am looking for an example script for using an if/then statement in Marketo.

We have an online form that will ask different questions, one of them being gender, and I want to populate a picture in the email that gets sent. Essentially, I'm looking for something that will do this:

```
if gender = male then display xyz.male.gif
if gender = female then display xyz.female.gif
```

If someone has an example Apache Velocity script (I've never used, so go ahead and laugh) I would be greatly in your debt. I can replicate really well, I just can't figure out from the tutorials how to make `foo = bar`.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use your conditional to create a variable containing the path of your image and then print it into your `img` tag (or wherever it needs to go).  Something like this:

```
#if ( $lead.Gender = Male )
    #set ( $image = "www.example.com/male.jpg" )
#else 
    #set ( $image = "www.example.com/female.jpg")
#end
<img src="${image}"></img>
```

There are some examples here as well:

[DOCUMENTATION / Email Scripting](https://developers.marketo.com/email-scripting/)

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much.

Follow up, do you recommend putting this as a token, in the mytokens section or just hard coding into the email?

Thanks again, I couldn't wrap my brain around this one!

Comment: All scripts for Marketo emails need to be added  as tokens, so you'll want to add this as a token to the parent program/folder of the email.

Answer (score 0):

A litle more advanced example:

```
#if ( ${lead.MarketoSocialGender} == "Male" )

    #set ( $image = "https://example.com/male.jpg" )

#elseif ( ${lead.MarketoSocialGender} == "Female" )

    #set ( $image = "https://example.com/female.jpg" )

#else

    #set ( $image = "https://example.com/other.jpg" )

#end

<img src="${image} >
```